# Getting Correct IPv6 Address from given prefix

Tags: windows-xp, ipv6, tcpip

On my windows xp machine, i have this information:

```
IP Address: fcb1:cafe:1:9e33::2
Default Gateway: fcb1:cafe:1:9e33::1
```

It works fine, and i can ping the gateway. However now there is another prefix for host given as:

```
fcb1:abab:cdcd:efe1::/64
```

To access this, i added static route to this IP via gateway:

```
netsh interface ipv6 add route fcb1:abab:cdcd:efe1:1::/64 "Local Area Connection" fcb1:cafe:1:9e33::1
```

This command was accepted successfully, but now when i try to ping:

```
ping6 fcb1:abab:cdcd:efe1:1
```

I get message: `Bad IPv6 address fcb1:abab:cdcd:efe1:1`

It seems the IP i am using is incorrect, however the host entry was accepted. Could someone suggest with the prefix: `fcb1:abab:cdcd:efe1::/64` what is a valid ip that i can ping???

I tried checking subnet calculator but they seem to detect this as incorrect, however this prefix is used on a valid system and is working fine, any idea??

Comment: Erm, are you missing the [second double point?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Address_representation) `ping6 fcb1:abab:cdcd:efe1::1`

Comment: @nixda, oh thank you so much, that was exactly the error, you solved the mistery!!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the [second colon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Address_representation) » `ping6 fcb1:abab:cdcd:efe1::1`

---

Since I don't like one-liners here's something most people probably don't know:

```
Wrong: 2001:0 db8 :: 0001 
Correct: 2001: db8 :: 1 
Leading zeros should be suppressed! 

Wrong: 2001: db8: 0:0:0:0:2:1 
Correct: 2001: db8 :: 2:1 
Wrong: 2001: db8 :: 0:1 
Correct: 2001: db8 :: 1 
The use of "::" must be carried out to the max! 

Wrong: 2001: db8 :: 1:1:1:1:1 
Correct: 2001: db8: 0:1:1:1:1:1 
A single 16-bit field with zeros can not be combined! 

Wrong: 2001 :: 1:0:0:0:1 
Correct: 2001:0:0:1 :: 1 
Have several options at the address with "::" to shorten  
the longest occurrence of zeros will be reduced! 

Wrong: 2001: db8: 0:0:1 :: 1 
Also wrong: 2001: db8 :: 1 :: 1 
Correct: 2001: db8 :: 1:0:0:1 
If multiple sequences are the same length of zeros,  
the first must be shortened! 

Wrong: 2001: db8: 0:0: A :: B 
Correct: 2001: db8: 0:0: a :: b 
The characters "a" through "f" must be lowercase!
```

[Source](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://security-planet.de/2010/08/23/die-richtige-schreibweise-von-ipv6-adressen/)

Comment: Concerning your list: RFC 5952 describes a _recommendation_, and none of the textual representations listed above as "Wrong" is really wrong (except for the spaces between the address parts, those are always wrong). They even MUST be accepted by every software implementing IPv6 addresses in textual form as they are legitimate addresses as described in RFC 4291. However, _if_ you claim to be compatible with RFC 5952, the "Wrong" address representations above MUST NOT be used.

Comment: @Dubu Good point. Feel free to edit the answer and include some references and explanations. :)